# WP All Import - Set product product status with xpath

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using "WP ALL IMPORT" to import products through xml. I have 3 different XML's. This proccess is run daily.
When editing template XML, in settings of template: 'Other Product options > Post status', there are 3 options to choose 1 of them: 'Published', 'Draft' and 'Set with Xpath'.
What i want is products to be set as 'draft' if quantity is less than 3, and 'Published' otherwise. Also everytime import run again (i use auto schedule) the post status has to be updated.
I used this expression for 'Set with Xpath':
*[quantity < 3] => draft | [quantity >= 3] => published*,
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.